# SPD2010-WorkFlow - how to get people picker value from Task form

Tags: 2010, workflow, people-picker, tasks

I have "Start Custom Task Process Action" and in task form fields I have a people picker. After task completed, I want to get selected user from people picker and use this value to send mail to this person.

How to achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **When Task Completes** step, you can add a **Send an Email** action.

Click **these users**.

In the To field, click the address book and select **Workflow Lookup for a User**

Data source: **Current Task**

Field from source: **your task form field**

Comment: Laurie, is it possible to save this value from people picker, to use it when creating new custom task process (in "with these users", and "these users" is a value from previous task from people picker)?

Comment: You could use a column in your list to hold this value and you could use the Association column in the ribbon to set one up if you don't already have a column. Inside the task process you have access to the list item that the workflow is running on. So, you can assign a value from your task into a field in your list item. And you can assign a value from a field in your list item to your task while inside of your task process.